# VBA Selecting the item indicated in the inputbox

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I would like after entering a date in the input box, I would like it to select a date or an entry in date_wb. However, my macro doesn't just finish it error free

```
'Open file
file_name = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Choose a target Workbook")
If file_name <> False Then
   'Set data file
   Set data_wb = Application.Workbooks.Open(file_name)
   
   'Input box

   Do
       inputbx = InputBox("Enter Date, FORMAT; YYY-MM-DD", , Format(VBA.Now, "YYYY-MM-DD"))
       If inputbx = vbNullString Then Exit Sub
       inputstr = Split(inputbx, "-")
       On Error Resume Next
       InputDate = DateSerial(inputstr(2), inputstr(0), inputstr(1))
       On Error GoTo 0
       DateIsValid = IsDate(InputDate)
       If Not DateIsValid Then MsgBox "Please enter a valid date.", vbExclamation
   Loop Until DateIsValid
```

Comment: `DateSerial` gets the parameters year, month, date (in that order). You ask the user to enter the date yyyy-mm-dd, in that case you need `DateSerial(inputstr(0), inputstr(1), inputstr(2))`.

Comment: Ok thanks, but its still not resolved problems :(

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Comment: Maybe it would help if you describe the problem. What happens, do you get a runtime error, is the final result not what you expect or is it blank?

Comment: It not selected result from inputbox in data_wb

Comment: Im Just put to inputbox 2020-02 for example and nothing happend How to change the code so that data_wb looks for

Answer (score 0):

I think the select part is missing you. If you want to find and select some date in another book you could do something like this:

```
Dim vDate As Date
Dim Loc As Range

'Open file
file_name = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Choose a target Workbook")
If file_name <> False Then
   'Set data file
   Set data_wb = Application.Workbooks.Open(file_name)
       
    Do
        inputbx = InputBox("Enter Date, FORMAT; YYYY-MM-DD", , format(VBA.Now, "YYYY-MM-DD"))
        If inputbx = vbNullString Then Exit Sub
        On Error Resume Next
        vDate = DateValue(inputbx)
        On Error GoTo 0
        DateIsValid = IsDate(vDate)
        If Not DateIsValid Then MsgBox "Please enter a valid date.", vbExclamation
    Loop Until DateIsValid
       
     
    For Each ws In data_wb.Worksheets
     ws.Activate
     With ws
        Set Loc = .Cells.Find(What:=vDate) 'It will find the firs cell that cointains the date as a date like (09/23/2021)
        If Not Loc Is Nothing Then
            Loc.Select
            Exit For
        End If
        
        Set Loc = .Cells.Find(What:=format(vDate, "yyyy-mm-dd")) 'It will find the date stored as a text like ('2021-09-23)
        If Not Loc Is Nothing Then
            Loc.Select
            Exit For
        End If
      End With
    Next
```

Just make shure how date is stored because it will find as value.

**Updated code.**

This find the date and copy the column range from line 109 to 123 from the found column.

```
Public Sub Main()

Dim vDate As Date
Dim Loc As Range

'Open file
file_name = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Choose a target Workbook")
If file_name <> False Then
   'Set data file
   Set data_wb = Application.Workbooks.Open(file_name)
       
    Do
        inputbx = InputBox("Enter Date, FORMAT; YYYY-MM-DD", , format(VBA.Now, "YYYY-MM-DD"))
        If inputbx = vbNullString Then Exit Sub
        On Error Resume Next
        vDate = DateValue(inputbx)
        On Error GoTo 0
        DateIsValid = IsDate(vDate)
        If Not DateIsValid Then MsgBox "Please enter a valid date.", vbExclamation
    Loop Until DateIsValid
       
     'The previous For each means will look for into all book sheet by sheet
     
     'If you want to look for into an sprecific sheet you have to do on this way
     data_wb.Worksheets("Final").Activate
     With data_wb.Worksheets("Final")
        Set Loc = .Cells.Find(What:=vDate) 'It will find the firs cell that cointains the date as a date like (09/23/2021)
        If Not Loc Is Nothing Then
            'This part just copy the range of 109 to 123 to the found column
            vArr = Split(Cells(1, Loc.Column).Address(True, False), "$")
            colLoc = vArr(0)
            data_wb.Worksheets("Final").Range(colLoc & "109:" & colLoc & "123").Copy
        End If
        
        Set Loc = .Cells.Find(What:=format(vDate, "yyyy-mm-dd")) 'It will find the date stored as a text like ('2021-09-23)
        If Not Loc Is Nothing Then
            'This code just select the range found
            Loc.Select
        End If
    End With
    
    
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much!  You are great.  and you can tell me what the code would look like if I would like to copy always the same range of lines 109: 123 in the column of this date that I choose in the input box

Comment: And my second qeustion is if i will looking only in one sheet in data_wb for example my sheet name is Final "   For Each ws In data_wb.Sheets("Final") isnt work

Comment: I updated the code, if this answer is helpful, mark it as correct, please